# Unit Testing for Floating-Point Equivalence in Perl

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testing, floating-point

I'm writing unit tests in Perl using [Test::More](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aMore). I'm used to some of the constructs from [cxxunit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cxxunit/), and in particular I'm missing [TS_ASSERT_DELTA](http://cxxtest.com/cxxtest/doc/guide.html#ts_assert_delta). For those who've not seen [TS_ASSERT_DELTA](http://cxxtest.com/cxxtest/doc/guide.html#ts_assert_delta), it looks like this:

```
TS_ASSERT_DELTA( 1.0, 1.1, 0.5 );   // this test will pass
TS_ASSERT_DELTA( 1.0, 1.1, 1e-10 ); // this test will fail
```

Is there a Perl equivalent for floating-point comparison? Or does everyone just write an obvious function for this? I'm currently working with this:

```
sub compare_float_delta {
    my $n1    = shift;
    my $n2    = shift;
    my $delta = shift;
    return( abs($n1-$n2) < $delta );
}
```

To me this seems like something the test framework should provide. Is that idea right, or should I just call float_compare_delta and move on with my life?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a specific module from CPAN: [Test::Number::Delta](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::Number::Delta)

Comment: A godsend! I was about to write it.

Answer (score 6):

See the [`num` function  in `Test::Deep`](http://p3rl.org/Test%3a%3aDeep#num-number-tolerance-).